# How to generate a list/table of all headings of a certain level in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, batch, cross-reference

Is there any automated way in Microsoft word to generate a list or fill a table with cross-references to all headings of a certain style in the document? Right now my only option is to manually click "Cross-reference", select the heading and click insert (Heading text). I have more than 100 headings, it would take a lot of time.

The idea behind this is to create a customized table of contents in a table with multiple columns with extra information about each heading.

Is VBA the only option?

Comment: Do they have an actual style applied or did you select a style and apply additional formatting? The default table of contents allows you to customize what it's based on and select what headings should appear at which level.

Comment: They are all the same style. The problem with the default table of contents is, you cannot display it in a table and have 4-5 columns for each entry and input custom information...

Comment: If you add 4-5 columns to a TOC you're not going to have enough space anyway. Giving an example of what you're trying to do with a picture might be helpful. As it is scripting might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Word has a built in function to customise Table of Contents.

Go to
`References` > `Table of Contents` > `Insert Table of Contents...`

A pop-up window  will open and you will be able to select if you want to display page number, right align them, select the type of Tab leader (.... or --- or ___ ), format in various styles (Template, Classic, Fancy, etc.).

You can further customise it using "Options" or "Modify" buttons.